# How to disregard the @sys-number to words

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

How can I do watson conversation to ignore a number written in a sentence don't converting to @sys-number?

Ex.: I want to give you A call.

In the case, the Watson understends 'A' with '1'. But I don't have this.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using this example to send the message, Watson Conversation shown to you what they understand (Intent, entities, etc).

You can use `.literal` method and show the number in the `cardinal` form, and you can use the @sys-number for getting this number in another answer, or in your application with one custom code.

**Example:**

```
I want to give you @sys-number.literal call.
```

In this case, you can check in this table how System entity `@sys-number` works:

[image]

**Obs.:** You can disable the `@sys-number` inside the System Entities and Watson won't try to identify the number inside your Conversation.

See the Official [documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/system-entities.html#system-entity-details) talking about System Entities within Watson Conversation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing the same behavior. I have sys-number turned on but it is not matching to the letter A. 
[image]